# How many subsample ways we normally have?

Tags: econometrics

I am wondering how many subsample ways or to get estimates for some sub-categories of the data without sub-sampling.

So far I know two approaches:

1> We can divide the whole sample into two subsamples and run the same main regression equation for these two subsamples and then comparing the coefficients of the variable of interest.

2> We can add the interaction between dummy representing for one subsample and the variable of interest [like this](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/45964/why-the-magnitude-of-coefficient-of-interest-decrease-drastically-when-adding-an).

I am wondering if we have any other way to do subsample?

Comment: Sub-sampling means dividing sample. Adding interaction term is not sub-sampling, actually the whole advantage of the method is to get estimates for some sub-categories of your data **without** sub-sampling.

Comment: @1muflon1, yes, I know what you mean, I will edit the question then